# Printing Overflown Text Of Page Footer To Next Page In JasperAssistant

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperAssistant to create a report. In my report I have a Text Field of specific size in Page Footer area.I have a requirement to print order numbers in that Text Field.If my order numbers can't fit in that Text Field in 1st Page then I have to print remaining order numbers in subsequent page footers.How can I achieve this? I tried various options like stretch with overflow to true, print repeated value to false but nothing works.

Can you please provide me any alternate suggestion if you have like using a sub report or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with multiple variables, something like:

```
v_ftr_chr_cnt  => 560
v_ord_num_len  => $F{ORDER_NUM}.length()
v_req_page_cnt => Math.ceil($V{v_ord_num_len}/$V{v_ftr_chr_cnt})
v_mod_page_num => $V{PAGE_NUMBER}-1 % $V{v_req_page_cnt}
v_substr_from  => $V{v_mod_page_num}*$V{v_ftr_chr_cnt}+1   //   1,  561, 1021...
v_substr_to    => ($V{v_mod_page_num}+1)*$V{v_ftr_chr_cnt} // 560, 1020, 1580...
v_footer => $F{ORDER_NUM}.Substring($V{v_substr_from}, ( $V{v_ord_num_len} >= $V{v_substr_to} ? $V{v_substr_to} : $V{v_ord_num_len}) )
```

And in footer band put text filed with this code:

```
$V{v_footer}
```

It looks ugly but it's simple. If you try to get sub-string that is longer then original string you will get exception that's why I check for string length on second parameter in sub-string operator. You didn't specify what happens depending on different length of order number, this footer will print entire order number on each page if it fits single page and if not it will print it on multiple pages, what happens if there is more pages then the length of order number you didn't specify... But I'm guessing that things could get quite complicated and ugly :)

**EDIT**

I've edited the code and it should cover the case when ORDER_NUM is shorter then the total count of pages, it will also print only a part that fits the first report. I'm not sure how you could get total page count to print the rest on new report. If you are not using summary band maybe you could print it as the last page and print the rest of the order number on it.

This would be the variable for the rest of the order number:

```
v_summary_ord_num => $F{ORDER_NUM}.SubString($V{v_ftr_chr_cnt}*($V{PAGE_NUMBER}-1))
```

And this would maybe work as "Print when expression" for summary band so you only print the band if ORDER NUM didn't fit on previous pages

```
$V{v_ord_num_len} > $V{v_ftr_chr_cnt}*$V{PAGE_NUMBER}
```

Comment: Hey, Another solution which don't need variable & no need to worry about total pages in report is $F{ORDER_NUM}.length() >=$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()*100 ? $F{ORDER_NUM}.substring(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()-1)*100,$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()*100) : ($F{ORDER_NUM}.length() >=($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()-1)*100 ? $F{ORDER_NUM}.substring(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()-1)*100) : null)

Comment: That is great I've missed that, but this wouldn't solve the issue if order number fits more than once in footers. You need to apply modulo to page number, I've edited my post and changed the code to cover that case

Answer (score 0):

I somehow find how can we add those order numbers which are not going to fit into the number of page generated by my main JasperPrint object to a new report. As you said we will first get the number of required pages like below

v_req_page_cnt => Math.ceil($V{v_ord_num_len}/$V{v_ftr_chr_cnt})

Then we will get the number of pages generated by main report by doing

mainReportPageCount = JapserPrint.getPages().size()

if (v_req_page_cnt > mainReportPageCount ) then generate a new report. Then getPages() from new report & add those pages to main report.